# Is MSOnline v1 powershell module is going to be deprecated?

Tags: powershell, office365, office365connectors

I noticed that MSOnline PowerShell 1.0 module is no longer available to download (download link from [ms online page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/msonline/?view=azureadps-1.0) says that 'Microsoft Connect Has Been Retired'), you can only install module in PS console:

```
Install-Module MSOnline
```

Is it first sign that it is going to deprecated? Or may be it is already? How long it will be available in PowerShell than?
V2 version doesn't cover all v1 functionality...

Comment: This sounds like something you should inquire about through [the Office365 feedback portal on UserVoice](https://office365.uservoice.com/), not StackOverflow

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's inquiring about a vendor's product roadmap rather than a question related to programming